# Problems when merging a sampled Observable

Tags: scala, rx-java, rx-scala

I'm using rx-scala, which is a subproject of rx-java. I'll be using Scala syntax and hope that everyone understands.

I'm encountering odd behavior, and I don't know whether it's a bug or misusage of rx operators on my behalf.

### Problem Statement

I have an `ox: Observable[X]` and a trigger observable `tr: Observable[()]`. I want an observable `oy` that is a transformation of `ox` using function `f: Function[X,Y]`, but only when triggered, since `f` is potentially expensive.

If there is no transformed value for the last value of `ox`, then `oy` should be `null`.

Some remarks:

- `ox` is hot, as it is the result of UI events.
- `ox` behaves correctly (both values and timing), as I checked with `println` debugging.
- `oy` fires at the correct times; it's just using outdated values of `ox`, when its a not-null value.

### Current Code

```
oy = ox.sample(tr).map(f).merge(ox.map(x => null))
```

The problem with the above code is: It works initally, but after some time, when triggering `tr`, `oy` is applying `f` to old values of `ox`. When not changing `ox`, if I trigger `tr` repeatedly, the results get newer and eventually catch up.

If I remove the `merge` to not reset to `null`, then everything works fine (probably, as the effect appears non-deterministic).

### Question

My presented code is buggy.

1. I'd like to know whether I'm doing something wrong.
2. I welcome alternative ways of achieving what I need.

### For the Jave people

- generics/type annotation: `ox: Observable[X]` means `Observable<X> ox`
- lambdas: `x => null` means `x -> null`

Comment: Could you translate this into regular Java?

Comment: @akarnokd I added a section for the Java folks, though I doubt it's really necessary. I think in the code line you only have to replace `=>` with `->`.

Comment: Assuming merge() here is mergeWith() in RxJava, you are double-consuming ox if it is cold, for every of its values you emit null and potentially a transformed value if triggered, which can get out-of-sync.

Comment: @akarnokd I checked the source of rx-scala, and `merge` is using the static `Observable.merge` (with two args) from rx-java under the hood. Also, as I understand, `ox` is hot, as it is the result of GUI events (edits on the `X`).

Comment: There are a few buffers involved in the chain above: the serialization in sample() and the front-buffers of merge. What is tr exactly? The delaying effect may happen with map() if it runs async in respect of the emission of the trigger value.

Comment: @akarnokd `tr` comes from a `JButton` producing `void` values from the clicked events. So far, the problem only happened *with* the merge. But since the sampled values are wrong then, something has to go wrong at the sample step already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78523/discussion-between-ziggystar-and-akarnokd).

Comment: Try `share`ing `ox` first: `val hotOx = ox.share; oy = hotOx.sample(tr).map(f).merge(hotOx.map(x => null))`, to rule out potentionally incorrectly implemented `ox`. Btw, in scala I'd use `Option` instead of `null`..

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using the following solution, which is short and apparently doesn't cause the problem to turn up:

```
tr.withLatestFrom(ox)((_,x) => f(x)) merge problem.map(_ => null)
```